# What do the indecomposable objects of the homotopy category of chain complexes look like?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, modular-representation-theory, chain-complexes

I am trying to understand indecomposable objects in the homotopy category of chain complexes. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category. Denote by $C(\mathcal{A})$ the category whose objects are chain complexes with objects from $\mathcal{A}$ and whose morphisms are chain maps. The category $C^b(\mathcal{A})$ is the full-subcategory whose objects are the bounded chain complexes. The category $K(\mathcal{A})$ is the category with the same objects as $C(\mathcal{A})$, but whose morphisms are homotopy classes of chain maps. The category $K^b(\mathcal{A})$ is the full-subcategory of $K(\mathcal{A})$ whose objects are the bounded complexes.

1. Is there any characterization of the indecomposable objects of $K(\mathcal{A})$? Does an indecomposable object of $C(\mathcal{A})$ remain indecomposable when viewed as an object $K(\mathcal{A})$, or vice-versa?
2. If $\mathcal{A}$ has the Krull-Schmidt theorem, does $K^b(\mathcal{A})$ have the Krull-Schmidt theorem? Specifically, I am interested in the case where $\mathcal{A} = {}_{kG}\mathrm{mod}$ is the category of finitely generated $kG$-modules and $k$ is a field or a complete commutative local Noetherian ring. In that case, $\mathcal{A}$ and $C^b(\mathcal{A})$ have the Krull-Schmidt theorem, but I can't seem to understand whether or not $K^b(\mathcal{A})$ does.

If any of these questions can be found in the literature, it would be very helpful to have the reference. Many thanks in advance for thinking about these questions.

Comment: Short answer: it's complicated. You will be able to answer this question for some $\mathcal{A}$ (e.g. for vector spaces), and not for others (e.g. it would imply an answer for $\mathcal{A}$ itself). It is known that $K^b(\mathcal{A})$ is Karoubian and a good reference is Schnürer's: "Homotopy categories and idempotent completeness, weight structures and weight complex functors". Hom spaces in $K^b$ are quot of Hom spaces in $C^b$, so if $C^b$ is Krull-Schmidt then so is $K^b$ because quot of a local ring is local. Another useful reference is "On the Karoubianess of a triangulated category".